# Xamarin.Forms Android project builds and runs locally on two machines; fails in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-devops, .net-standard

I have a solution that contains an ASP.Net Core web-api project, a Xamarin.Forms app with an Android, iOS and Shared Netstandard library project, along with 5 other NetStandard libraries that are shared between the Xamarin app and the ASP.Net Core app.

I am able to compile and run the Android app on two different local machines, one being Windows 10 and another being macOS Sierra. When I have Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) clone the repository from BitBucket and build the Android project, it fails to build because of Android resource file issues. I assume the problem is that I don't have VSTS configured correctly, since this runs on two different machines for me without issue. I'm not sure what I have misconfigured in VSTS to solve the issue.

I have a [complete reproducible project available for download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxvqqQ3_PQYxanRXc2p0Nm11T1k/view?usp=sharing) for uploading to VSTS if anyone needs that.

The build output is large, so I've included the errors themselves below with [a link to the entire build output](https://gist.github.com/scionwest/eb899e5afed59f01bb0f853a03c0fd90) from VSTS.

> "d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj" (PackageForAndroid target) (1) ->
>   (_UpdateAndroidResgen target) -> 
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(3): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'. >[d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000:  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(5): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(4): error APT0000:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]
>   Resources\values\styles.xml(5): error APT0000:  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. [d:\a\1\s\dotnet\Apps\Mobile\Mobile.Android\Mobile.Android.csproj]

The following is my VSTS Build Definition:

### NuGet Restore

[image]

### Android build

[image]

### Definition Options

[image]

What have I got configured incorrectly that's causing this to fail with the Android resources in VSTS, but not when I build locally?

### Local Environment

- Windows

  - Operating System: Windows 10
  - Visual Studio 2017 15.3 Preview 3
  - `dotnet --version`: 1.1.0-preview1-005051
- Mac

  - Operating System: Sierra 10.12.5
  - Visual Studio for Mac Community - 7.1 Preview (build 583)

    - Alpha Channel
  - `dotnet --version`: 2.0.0-preview3-006815

### App Info

- Xamarin.Forms shared NetStandard library packages:

  - Xamarin.Forms: 2.3.5.256-pre6
  - NetStandard.Library: 1.6.1
- Xamarin.Android packages

  - Xamarin.Android.Support.Design: 25.3.1
  - Xamarin.Android.Support.v4: 25.3.1
  - Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat: 25.3.1
  - Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView: 25.3.1
  - Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter: 25.3.1
- Xamarin.Android Framework

  - MonoAndroid, Version=v7.1
- Minimum Android Version: 4.4, API Level 19
- Target Android Version: 7.1, API Level 25
- Target Framework: 7.1

### Final thoughts

I am using `project.json` for the Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects to maange the nuget packages, instead of packages.config, so I can use transitive dependencies. Is there something specific about my two environments that I need to configure in VSTS? I'm using two different versions of `dotnet core` as well without any issues, so I'm really confused what's going on here.

Comment: Take it step by step as if you were a build machine. For example, instead of building your app in VS/VS4M, try to run the command line `msbuild` against your freshly cloned project in these environments. My guess is that the `Resource.designer.cs` is not being updated with the proper items from the `AppCompat` theme. Perhaps try the `UpdateAndroidResources` target prior to using `SignAndroidPackage` - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Build_Targets

Comment: I looked at your link - I understand the targets and stuff a bit now. Do you have any specific reading material that you would recommend for someone who's never done anything with msbuild? All of my experience has been either dotnet core cli or VS/VS4M.

Comment: I had a presentation handy that I converted to a quick blog: http://www.jon-douglas.com/2017/07/26/msbuild-basics/ See the bottom for more materials/resources.

Comment: I can pass the .csproj file directly into msbuild and it builds without issue

Comment: I went to my build output log and copied the msbuild command used to start the build. Excluding the logging components of the command, I copy/pasted locally and executed. The app compiled without issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the new projects? Can you share the simple projects on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Do you have a contact email I can send the download link to?

Comment: You can share the simple sample projects (not original projects) on the OneDrive.

Comment: Alright - i'll try to get something put together over the next or so since recreating a xamarin vsts build issue will take a decent amount of time. Have to create a new VS project, new repo, convert to netstandard, and then start down the road of adding a dependency, check in code, queue build-> repeat until i can figure out what's causing it to break. Since a new project work fine, i'll have to slowly re-construct how mine is setup until it breaks (be much easier to just give you the original project which has no IP in it i'm concerned about sharing with Microsoft.)

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent to run the build? What's the result if you configure a build agent on one of the two local machines and then run a build with it?

Comment: @starain-MSFT A working, minimal reproducible, is [available for download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxvqqQ3_PQYxanRXc2p0Nm11T1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I am using the Hosted VS2017 option. I have uploaded a project reproducing this issue (in comment above and updated OP). I will take a look at using a build agent on a local machine. DevOps in general is outside of my comfort zone, so it will take some time for me to try getting one setup (reading the docs now)

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Have you tried the solution in my answer?

Comment: I haven't, my MacBook battery started swelling so I'm out of a machine until the battery gets delivered. I will as soon as the battery arrives though. Thanks for following up

Answer (score 2):

Use "Visual Studio Build" task instead of "Xamarin.Android" task to run the build. Add `/t:PackageForAndroid` argument in the task if you want to generate apk package.
[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Guess the two builds do stuff differently.  Was Xamarin.Forms though.